# Angular error ReferenceError: $Value is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I am getting a list from html file and I am passing it to backend for processing. I have an error which says `ReferenceError: $Value is not defined`

In my controller file I have a function test. The error is in `$scope.result = $Value.getVal(data);`

```
test = function test($scope, $timeout, $routeParams, Value) {
  getVal = fucntion getVal(list) {
    var data = list....
    $scope.result = $Value.getVal(data);
  },
  start = function start() {
    $scope.info = getVal;
  };
  start();
};
angular.module('myApp').controller('test', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$routeParams', test]);
```

...

Comment: You need to inject the $Value service in your controller test

Comment: @koolunix thanks how can I do it?

Comment: You are injecting 'Value' in your controller 'test' right now. Do you mean '$Value'?

Comment: when I inject $Value it shows another error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'getVal' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Value` to the Inline Annotation list:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('test', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$routeParams', 'Value', test]);
```

And call it like so:

```
$scope.result = Value.getVal(data);
```

Comment: Thanks IIan. When I added 'Value' it showed me an error `This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency`

Comment: Is it something related to my service?

Comment: Can you please say what you want to achieve?